# Makefile:2: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

I have two .cpp files namely `decryptor.cpp` and `prod-ent.cpp`.
I have created a Makefile to for the compilation of both the files in Linux platform.

```
all: decryptor.cpp prod-ent.cpp
       g++ prod-ent.cpp -o prod-ent -g
       g++ decryptor.cpp -o decryptor -g -lcryptopp
clean:
       rm prod-ent
       rm decryptor
```

Whenever I'm trying to execute the Makefile its showing me the following error:

> Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.

I am new to create makefiles and cannot figure out my fault. Please help me in correcting the code.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Indentation matters in Makefiles, so please make sure to post an accurate representation. What you posted looks wrong (leading spaces before targets, `all` and `clean` misaligned.)

Comment: I remember having this problem with manually-generated makefiles a few times... I think you need to use a tab character to indent the compilation commands, rather than a series of spaces.

Comment: Tabs are given in front of "g++"s and "rm"s in all the occurrences and  a space is given between the two file-names and in between the options. Still it doesn't work

Comment: Please verify you're using tabs instead of spaces

Comment: I had also same issue but using different editor i have tried it give tab and its working.

Answer (score 196):

You need a real tab instead of space in front of `g++` and `rm` commands. If still fails
then your editor is inserting spaces instead, even if you're hitting the tab key on your keyboard. You need to configure your editor to insert hard tabs (09 in ASCII) instead.

Like

```
all: decryptor.cpp prod-ent.cpp
*****g++ prod-ent.cpp -o prod-ent -g
*****g++ decryptor.cpp -o decryptor -g -lcryptopp
clean:
*****rm prod-ent
*****rm decryptor
```

Instead `*****` replace TAB.

You can check your side by command

```
cat -e -t -v  makefile
```

It's show line starting by `^I` if `TAB` is given to that line and it end the line by `$`.

Also you can do by `;`

```
all: decryptor.cpp prod-ent.cpp ; g++ prod-ent.cpp -o prod-ent -g ; g++ decryptor.cpp -o decryptor -g -lcryptopp
clean: ; rm prod-ent ; rm decryptor
```

Comment: why would the error message not say this?